# How to use retry on rxjs ReplaySubject

Tags: javascript, observable, rxjs

I'm creating the class below to facilitate a one way data flow.  Is there a way to make the `outputError` method not render the observable inoperable?  I tried adding `subject.retry()`, as you can see below, but it results in an infinite loop.  Can an error be output and then do something to prevent `subject.retry()` from getting that error each time it tries to reconnect?

Here is part of the class I created:

```
/**
 * Output data to be received by observe command of the same name
 * @param name The name that will be listened for by observe
 * @param data An object passed to observables success handler
 */
prototype.output = function (name, data) {
    this._getReference('output', name).observer.onNext(data);
};

/**
 * Listen for an output with the given name
 * @param name The output name which is listened for
 * @returns An observable instance
 */
prototype.observe = function (name) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) throw new Error('Radio Channel: The observe method takes only one argument.');
    return this._getReference('output', name).observable;
};

/**
 * Output an error to be received by observe command
 * @param name  The name that will be listed for by observe
 * @param error An error object passed to observables error handler
 */
prototype.outputError = function(name, error) {
    this._getReference('output', name).observer.onError(error);

};

//Returns existing subject or creates a new one if it does not exist
prototype._getReference = function(type, name) {
      name = this._createName(name);
        var lookup = this['_' + type];
        var result = lookup[name];

        if (!result){
            var subject = new rx.ReplaySubject(1);
            lookup[name] = {
                observable: subject, //.retry() results in infinite loop
                observer: subject
            } ;
            result = lookup[name];
        }

        return result;
};

//Creates a consistent, non-integer key name
prototype._createName = function (name) {
    return '$' + name;
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
channel.observe('refresh').subscribe(onLoaded, onError);
```

Without calling `subject.retry()`, the onError function is called, but then onLoaded will never be called again.  I realize I can output an error object with `error: true` to the onLoaded function, but I would prefer to encapsulate the change rather than change the interface of the class, as well as having two separate functions for handling success and error.

Answer (score 0):

The [retry](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator resubcribes to the subject in hope of not receiving an onError event this time around. However, as you explicitly call onError(error), the same thing has to happen again - after all you are using a ReplaySubject and thereby just replaying the previous sequence.

Retry is meant to be used with observables that can have different output each time they are run. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hanezoradu/1/edit?js,console)

```
var counter = 0;
var respond = 4
var observable = Rx.Observable
    .create(observable => {
      if(counter == respond) {
        observable.onNext('response');
        observable.onCompleted();                  
      } else {
        observable.onError('error');
        counter++; 
      }
    })
    .retry(respond + 1);

observable.subscribe(value => console.log(value),
                     error => console.log(error));
```

Notice that retry retries n-1 times (retry(1) does not retry at all). If you were to lower the number of times to retry, the observable would fail. The way it is now is it returns 'response' completes sucessfully.

Would it be possible to send observables into your ReplaySubject and just concatMap the subject to get the values?